# Yeshello signup form

Tags: html, forms, subscription

I need a little button on my site so people can subscribe to my newsletter.

Here is what i have:

```
<form name="yeshello" method="post" target="_blank" action="https://forms.yeshello.net/sub.htm?mycode"> <input type="text" name="email"> <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"</form>
```

Now the responseType needs to be 0
and the successUrl needs to be http://www.myspecificthankyoupage.html

How to get the responsetype and succesUrl in the code?
From what I understood both can be sended as a hidden field in the web form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out. The reason it didn't work because i was given the wrong url.

Here is the right code:

```
    <form name="yeshello" method="post" target="_blank" action="https://www.yeshello.net/myuniquecode">
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
        <input type="hidden" name="responseType" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="http://myrequestedwebsiteurl" />
    </form>
```